# Can I bind to a function that takes default arguments and then call it?

Tags: c++, c++11, bind, default-arguments

How can I bind to a function that takes default arguments, without specifying the default arguments and then call it without any arguments?

```
void foo(int a, int b = 23) {
  std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  auto f = std::bind(foo, 23, 34); // works
  f();


  auto g = std::bind(foo, 23); // doesn't work
  g();

  using std::placeholders::_1;
  auto h = std::bind(foo, 23, _1); // doesn't work either 
  h();

}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". The code would compiles if you gave different names to the variables.

Comment: why do you keep reassigning to f?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes yeah sorry, example was incomplete. updated code

Comment: @111111 that was more of a symbolic mean. updated code

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Basically, any time you write `foo(x)` the compiler translates it to `foo(x, 23);`. It only works if you actually have a directly call with the function name. You can' t, for example, assign `&foo` to a `void(*)(int)`, because the function's signature is `void(int, int)`. Default parameters play no part in the signature. And if you assign it to a `void(*)(int, int)` variable, the information about the default parameter is lost: you can't take advantage of the default parameter through that variable. `std::bind` stores a `void(*)(int, int)` somewhere in its bowels, and thus loses the default parameter information.

There is no way in C++ to get the default value of a parameter from outside the function, so you're stuck with manually providing the default value when you bind.

Answer (score 11):

I think you could simulate the behaviour you want using a lambda.

Something along the lines of this:

```
auto g = [] (){ foo( 23 ); };
```

EDIT: Just checked, and seems to work fine: http://ideone.com/SPSvi

Comment: Use could also use this to call the function without parameters, but still preserve the ability to pass something in for b: ```auto g = [](int b = 23) { foo(23, b); };```

Answer (score 3):

I have two solutions:

1 - You can overload foo() and have it call the original with defaults:

```
void foo(int a, int b) 
{
    std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
}

inline void foo(int a)
{
    foo(a, 23);
}
```

2 - You can use a static variable as default and then use it in the binding process:

```
static int foo_default_b = 23;
void foo(int a, int b = foo_default_b) 
{
    std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
}

auto g = std::bind(foo, 23, foo_default_b);
g();
```

Answer (score -4):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931846/boostbind-for-a-member-function-with-default-value) disagrees with R. Martinho Fernandes' answer. You can indeed use `boost::bind` to bind to the default parameters, you just need to put placeholders in, as so:

```
boost::bind<void (int, int)>(foo, _1, _2)(12);
```

This will call `foo(12, 23)`, as expected. Although I didn't test this specific code, I've done something similar in my code based on the answer linked above, and it works in `gcc 4.8.5`.

Hmm, I just noticed that this is asking about `std::bind`, not `boost::bind`. I don't know what differences there are, if any.

Comment: "Although I didn't test this specific code" explains why this doesn't work on GCC 4.8.5 (or any other version) with any version of Boost (from 1.49.0 to 1.64.0). The "This answer" which you referenced does **not** say that you can call the bind expression *without* the defaulted parameters, but rather explains that you can either bind a specific value or be required to pass an argument. R. Martinho Fernandes' answer is correct, you cannot call the bind expression this way (neither using `boost:bind` nor `std::bind`).